# How to split code in multiple files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to split my code in multiple files but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

I have 3 files, main.js, common.js and doSomething.js. `common.browser` is a chrome instance so it's important that it only gets launched once and that I can access it from every file.

In my code below, it's not working. `common.browser` is undefined in `doSomething.print()`

```
//File 1: main.js
(async() => {
    const common = require('./common')
    const doSomething = require('./doSomething')

    await common.init()
    doSomething.print() //<-- prints 'undefined'
})()



//File 2: common.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
let common = {}

common.init = async () => {   
    common.browser = await puppeteer.launch()   
}

module.exports = common



//File3: doSomething.js
const common = require('./common')
let doSomething = {}
const browser = common.browser //<-- Added this and it makes it not work.

doSomething.print = () => {
    console.log(browser)
}

module.exports = doSomething
```

Comment: Try adding .js to each of the files, at least that's the way I do it, also try require_once

Comment: `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')` - try typing here `./puppeteer`, you're missing `./`

Comment: `doSomething.print() //<-- returns undefined` Is .print undefined, or does it return undefined ? Because if the function print returns undefined, its normal.

Comment: @FrançoisP. is right - if you don't `return` anything from a function, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @FrançoisP. common.browser is undefined

Comment: Okay, so the problem is the way you use the `.this` keyword. Write `common.browser = await puppeteer.launch()`instead. I will write an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisP. Thanks that works, but in my original program it has a slightly different set up that still doesn't work. Can you look at my edited question?

Comment: I posted an answer for the initial question, it shows you how to build a constructor as well, I can also show you the class syntax (which is more ES6 style)

Comment: I'm checking your edited question

Comment: You must call `common.init()` before requiring `doSomething` if you need `doSomething` to use `common.browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `common.js` file you are setting `this.browser = await puppeteer.launch()` here, the keyword `this` does not refer to the object `common`.

You could simply use the object common.

```
//File 2: common.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
let common = {}

common.init = async () => {   
    common.browser = await puppeteer.launch()   
}

module.exports = common
```

Or if you want to use `this`, you must give common a constructor and instantiate it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const common = function() {}

common.prototype.init = async function() {   
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch() 
};

module.exports = new common()
```

Same as before with class syntax (you need node 8.xx)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

class Common {
    constructor() {}

    async init() {
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    }
}

module.exports = new Common();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was testing with the solution and I was getting an error. I could make it work adding "async" in the file 3. I changed the names of the files, and I added some data, sorry about that.

```
// file 1: index.js
(async () => {
  const common = require('./common')
  const actions = require('./actions')

  await common.init()
  actions.web() //<-- open google.com in browser
})()

// file 2: common.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
let common = {}

common.init = async () => {
  common.browser = await puppeteer.launch({

    headless: false,
    slowMo: 50 // slow down by 50ms
    //devtools: true
  })

  common.page = await common.browser.newPage()
}

module.exports = common

// file 3: actions.js
const common = require('./common')
let actions = {}

actions.web = async () => {
  await common.page.goto('https://google.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  })
}

module.exports = actions
```